# AngularJs gm.datepickerMultiSelect, bad date

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I am trying to use the [gm.datepickerMultiSelect](https://github.com/spongessuck/gm.datepickerMultiSelect) module in AngularJS. I have a day offset when I select a date and I have located the line that causes me problem in the library:

```
var dateVal = Date.parse($filter('gmISODate')(newVal)),
```

Can somebody help me?

**More informations :**
I have copy past sample from http://plnkr.co/edit/7rKzFo?p=preview

when I select a date (2016/12/20) then
newVal = "Tue Dec 20 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid)"

The problem is the GMT+1 loosed when it passes through the filter
date.toISOString().split("T")[0] give me "2016-12-19"

Comment: I'm not sure what with what you are actually asking. Are you saying that the whenever you select a date from the `gm.datepickerMultiSelect`, the returned date is a day off (which way?), and you want to know how to fix it? You've said you have found the line that you believe gives you a "bad" date, but as the (library's example](http://plnkr.co/edit/iVSdXt?p=preview) appears to work fine, it's unlikely to be the problem. How you're using it is. Can you therefore please include a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: i have add some information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution

I've replace

```
.filter('gmISODate', function () {
    return function (date) {
        return date.toISOString().split("T")[0];
    }
})
```

by

```
.filter('gmISODate', function () {
    return function (date) {
        var m = moment(date);
        return m.format()
    }
})
```

Note : moment.js library at : http://momentjs.com/